# A função não funciona

Tags: javascript

Tentei usar o código abaixo para calcular o IMC da pessoa, mas ele não funciona:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

var pulalinha = function() {
    document.write("<br>");
}
var mostra = function(frase){
    document.write(frase);
    pulalinha();
    pulalinha();
};

var calculaIMC = function(altura, peso){
    var imc = peso / (altura * altura);
    return imc;
}

var nome = prompt("Bom dia, qual seu nome?");
document.write("Seja bem vindo, " + nome);

var idade = prompt(nome + ", quantos anos você tem?");
document.write(nome + " tem " idade + "anos");

var peso = prompt(nome + ", qual seu peso?");
document.write(nome + " tem" + peso + "quilos.");

var altura = prompt(nome + ", qual sua altura?");
document.write(nome + " tem " + altura + "de altura.");

var imcDaPessoa = calculaIMC(altura, peso);
mostra("Seu IMC é: " + imc);
mostra("Você está " + (imc - 18.5) + " pontos acima do seu peso ideal.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tem erro de sintaxe, faltando um sina l de mais na concatenação de textos e também acessava a variável `imc` que não existia naquele contexto, quando dá nome para uma variável, tem que usar esse nome, não pode usar outro. Fiz outras melhorias também. Agora fazer outras melhorias por cinta própria.

```js
var pulalinha = function() {
    document.write("<br>");
}
var mostra = function(frase) {
    document.write(frase);
    pulalinha();
    pulalinha();
};
var calculaIMC = function(altura, peso) {
    return peso / (altura * altura);
}
var nome = prompt("Bom dia, qual seu nome?");
document.write("Seja bem vindo, " + nome);
var idade = prompt(nome + ", quantos anos você tem?");
document.write(nome + " tem " + idade + "anos");
var peso = prompt(nome + ", qual seu peso?");
document.write(nome + " tem" + peso + "quilos.");
var altura = prompt(nome + ", qual sua altura?");
document.write(nome + " tem " + altura + "de altura.");
var imcDaPessoa = calculaIMC(altura, peso);
mostra("Seu IMC é: " + imcDaPessoa);
mostra("Você está " + (imcDaPessoa - 18.5) + " pontos acima do seu peso ideal.");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Imc.js).

Comment: Legal! Isso é algo que ainda me pega, preciso ler com mais atenção o código, muito obrigado por responder. Possui algum link onde exista exercícios de javascript com solução pra que eu possa treinar? Obrigado pela atenção!